# Blat to mail .csv attachment

Tags: email, email-attachments, blat

I can use Blat to mail the contents of a .csv file, which are printed in the mail body itself

```
blat "c:\some.txt" -t someone@somwhere.com -s "Some Subject"
```

but if I add the attach or attachi switch, the program just hangs

```
blat -attach "c:\some.txt" -t someone@somwhere.com -s "Some Subject"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out it should be

```
blat -s "Some Subject" -i "Someone Somewhere" -to someone@somewhere -body "Please see attached." -attach "C:\some.txt"
```